# Page ignores style sheet but reads same style in the header

Tags: css

This page doesn't get the table styles from the style sheet.  If I put the same styles in the page itself, they are applied.  What could cause this? The css file name is correct and is read by other pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Pagelinks | Known Issues</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pagelinks_windows.css" />

<!-- style>
#known_issues th, #known_issues td {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
}

</style -->

</head>
<body>
<h1>Known Issues</h1>

<p>
Known bugs and issues are listed here.</p>

<table id="known_issues">
<tr><th>Tracking No.</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th><th>Status</th><th>Workaround</th></tr>
<tr><td>plt001</td><td>Site</td><td>Site navigation broken on Internet Explorer 8</td><td>Closed</td><td>None. That browser version has a major bug involving javascript objects. Users must upgrade to Internet Explorer 9.</td></tr>
<tr><td>plt002</td><td>Site</td><td>Saints and feasts do now show description</td><td>Open</td><td>None. The description data for the Saints and the feasts is being compiled.</td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Test if the content of the css file is visible. 
Try to open it in the browser.

Common possible error when letters-case (A\a and so on) in file-names differs - this willn't work on *nix hosting servers, ever if it worked localy on windows.

Another common situation: when is error in path to file from current file-directory.

Answer (score 1):

Are your stylesheets in the same root directory as this `html` file?  Common practice is to put stylesheets, js, includes, etc into different directories.  Perhaps you follow this convention and simply forgot `href="css/pagelinks_windows.css"`?  Hard to find the answer to your problem without much more information but it's usually something small you're missing.  One of those that you end up with a forehead-slap once you find it :)

Comment: Also noticed you are using an older library of jQuery.  Is this intentional?  I believe the newest version is 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

What does your stylesheet look like?
I think you might have some conflicting css, try adding your table style at the VERY bottom of pagelinks_windows.css